# Prevent html5 "required" attribute on Django required form fields

Tags: django, html, django-forms

I've got a Django form with required fields, but I don't want them to render with the html `required` attribute because I want to control this from Javascript.

How can I make the form render without the `required` attribute, while still being validated required server-side.

Answer (score 1):

On the form, set

```
use_required_attribute = False
```

See:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.use_required_attribute

Comment: I've followd the same thing and added this attribute to Form items, but got TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_required_attribute'